# What difference does it make while using switch-case vs. if-else for radioGroup in Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-service, android-arrayadapter

Right now I use switch-case

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
        {
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                switch(checkedId){
                    case R.id.Eng:
                        // do operations specific to this selection
                        setLocale("en_US");
                        Intent intentEng = new Intent(getActivity(), Some.class);
                        startActivity(intentEng);
                        break;

                    case R.id.French:
                        // do operations specific to this selection
                        setLocale("fr");
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Some.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });
```

What happens is sometimes I click first radio button and I immediately click second one as well.

Within the case block I pass the intent to a Service class which talks to web services and updates an arrayAdapter for ListView.

Since I quickly click both radio buttons, the UI gets results of both the languages (case blocks). 
1) How to avoid this ?
2) Does using switch case in place of if-else matters in these issues?

Answer (score 1):

After receiving onCheckedChanged event disable your radio buttons

Comment: I would like to disable the entire screen(I mean showing a transparent glass pane kinda layer on top of the existing activity) and show loading symbol until I show next activity. How to do that?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I mean calling setEnabled(false) method on your RadioButton objects. After that they stop receiving any user interactions. For showing loading symbols you should consider using of ProgressDialog. In case of progress dialog you don't have to disable RadioButtons, but short time dialog looks like blinking. Please check both ways...

Answer (score 1):

It is completely depends on Your UI. you disable the radio buttons after "onCheckedChanged" called also not correct. because after selecting one language user may be want to change the selection, so you should provide confirmation component in the UI.

What is the difference here if we use the switch case or if-else for your scenario.

Comment: I would like to disable the entire screen(I mean showing a transparent glass pane kinda layer on top of the existing activity) and show loading symbol until I show next activity. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I may be misunderstanding what you are doing but assuming you are launching and showing another activity on top of the current one you can call `finish()` after starting the new activity.

Otherwise you can declare a `boolean` field `shouldHandleCheckChanged` or something to keep track of whether to process any of the cases in`onCheckChanged()`.  You could set the value to false right after starting the new activity and then set it to true once you receive whatever update you are expecting.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, in your activity class make a boolean field:

```
Private isLoadingNewActivity = false;
```

In your onResume make it false:

```
isLoadingNewActivity = false;
```

And in your listener check it:

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener()
    {
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            If(isLoadingNewActivity)
            return;
            switch(checkedId){
                case R.id.Eng:
                    // do operations specific to this selection
                    setLocale("en_US");
                    Intent intentEng = new Intent(getActivity(), Some.class);
                    startActivity(intentEng);
                    isLoadingNewActivity = true; 
                    break;

                case R.id.French:
                    // do operations specific to this selection
                    setLocale("fr");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Some.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    isLoadingNewActivity = true;
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Shouldn't `isLoadingNewActivity = false;` be called when the `adapter` updates the data? `onResume` may never be called as OP is starting a `Service`.

Comment: The question doesnt contain any sevice starting . Its juat about openning another activity.

Comment: Right. Quoting OP "Within the case block I pass the intent to a Service class which talks to web services". I just read this and skipped the "startActivity()" part